# My regex should match 3 times, but matches only twice (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I have a small code snippet with a regex to match a numerical value, followed by an optional text in rectangular brackets, ended by the character 'A'. An example is

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+)(?:\[(.*)\])?A/", "123[SomeText]A345[SomeOtherText]A678A", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

and the expected result is to have three matches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123[SomeText]A
            [1] => 345[SomeOtherText]A
            [2] => 678A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 345
            [2] => 678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SomeText
            [1] => SomeOtherText
            [2] => 
        )
)
```

while the above code only matches twice:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123[SomeText]A345[SomeOtherText]A
            [1] => 678A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SomeText]A345[SomeOtherText
            [1] => 
        )
)
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong in the given regex. Any suggestions for fixing the regex are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#greedy). Quantifiers (like `.*`) consume as much as possible. And since `.` can also match `]` it just goes past the first closing `]` to the last one. You could make the repetition ungreedy (matching as little as possible), by using `.*?`. But there's a better (faster) option in your case. Make sure, that you cannot go past the closing `]`, by removing it from the allowed characters:

```
/([0-9]+)(?:\[([^\]]*)\])?A/
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/4UDWmr)

Note that you don't actually have to escape the closing bracket, because it is the first character in the class (and because empty classes are not allowed, you don't need to escape it) - and the other one is outside a class, so it can't be a closing bracket either:

```
/([0-9]+)(?:\[([^]]*)])?A/
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/ZHtITl)

Which variant you prefer is a matter of taste, I'd say.

Comment: I thought it might be related to 'greediness', but I was not sure how/where to take it into account. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Excellent description of not only a correct answer but of additional levels of regex understanding needed to truly _craft_ a fast and accurate solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

The .* is greedy, so change it:

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+)(?:\[([^A]*)\])?A/", "123[SomeText]A345[SomeOtherText]A678A", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Try it out: http://3v4l.org/BZgmH

Answer (score 0):

how about this pattern?

```
\d+(\[.*?\])?A
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're pretty sure that your texts are not containing 'A' character, then this should work:

```
'/(\d*)([^A]*)/'
```

but if each parts ends with new part which has a number in the beginning this should work:

```
'/(\d*)([^\d]*)/'
```

with this line

```
preg_match_all('/(\d*)([^\d]*)/', "123[SomeText]A345[SomeOtherText]A678A", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```